# Trouble installing packages in a fresh Ubuntu chroot

Tags: ubuntu, apt, chroot

I created a chroot using the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot), substituting `focal` for `lucid`. Now I'd like to start installing packages, starting with Python, but I'm not sure what kind of setup I need to perform before doing so.

Currently when I try to install `software-properties-common` (via `apt-get`), I get the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
software-properties-common : Depends: gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 (>= 1.1.0-2) but it 
is not installable
                             Depends: packagekit but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Googling tells me that `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` might turn something up, but it does not.

I thought it might be an issue with `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so I copied that in from the outer installation and refreshed but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the security repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

providing `gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0` and `packagekit`.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this (replacing `bionic` with `focal`) and refreshed via `apt-get update` but I'm still getting the same error. `apt-cache policy` comes up empty for these packages.